# JqueryUI Slider: Take the slider handleout of the tabindex/ Edit: Still looking for answers

Tags: jquery-ui

I would like to have the tabstops only stop on the input fields and not on the sliders.

Jquery UI Slider does not work on input tags, but unfortunately the html code tabindex="-1" requires input, button, textarea. Is there a way to remove the tabstops from the slider?

```
<div id="slider-vertical" style="float:left;" tabindex="-1"></div>


$("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    animate: 500,
    min: 0,
    max: 8760,
    value: 1500,
    step: 10,
    slide: refreshCalculation,
    change: refreshCalculation
});
```

Edit: Seems like this is kind of a niche problem. Does anyone have any idea how to adress this. I assume that it was added as a feature to the slider and could be located somewhere in the jQueryUI js-file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you change the tabindex on a jQuery UI's slider Handle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650802/how-can-you-change-the-tabindex-on-a-jquery-uis-slider-handle)